# Mosaic to raster 16BIT Error 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, mosaic, error-999999

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1. I am trying to merge a few 16bit rasters by Mosaic to New Raster. The problem is it makes me do only a 8bit output making me lose pixel data bigger than 255 and classifying them as 255. Also, it makes the mosaic only if I choose PNG as output format. I need a 16BIT mosaic as output, like the input rasters, but it gives me back always Error 999999.
Michael, honestly I'm making a huge mess with the mosaic dataset... even though spatial reference and bands are the same... let's keep trying with Mosaic to New Raster.. this is one of the raster I am using for the mosaic...[image]

Comment: PNG only supports 8 bit, change your output type to TIFF or IMG for 16bit support. Even better still create a mosaic dataset, add your rasters then right click, export... but definitely save as IMG or TIFF. Have you got mixed 8, 16 and 32 bit images? Are they all integer or do you have some floating point?

Comment: They all are 16bit images and all integer. I tried TIFF and IMG with 16bit but gives back Error 999999 yet... Can you tell me more about the mosaic dataset? I tried but I just made a mess...

Comment: Sure, you create a mosaic dataset in a file geodatabase (enter spatial reference and bands) then right click on it and select Add Rasters to add rasters to it - they're not *actually* added, only referenced, so the data stays right where it is. After you've added the rasters right click on the mosiac dataset and then export... if you're still having troubles I can put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Arcmap 10.1
you can use an alternative option:
1. add your all geo-refed raster in a new arcmap
2. define the projection properly in the data frame properties
3. Go to windows menu and click on image analysis.
4. In image analysis tool select all your rasters and click on mosaic button present in a window below named "processing".
5. A temporary raster add in table of contents, finally export it in tif or img format because you have 16bit data.[image]

Comment: That's a very cool option. How about the mosaic operator? I need to get the maximum value in the overlapping area.